# angular clean code structure, one controller per file

Tags: angularjs

I am reading how to write a [clean code](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075) as I am learning the basics of this framework.
If I understand correctly, it is preferred to have one Controller per file, and one module per file but that will end up making my index.html head tag so long if I have to link to all those controllers.js files in the head.

Please look at the image below.
Am I missing something?  Thanks

[image]

Comment: doing this manually is not simple or efficient. As mentioned by @Kertis using task automation tools is the way to go. There are lots of scaffolds out there that have all the tools and templates set up to make it easy. For example generator-gulp-angular if all you want is a front end angular project. There are numerous mean stack seeds also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use any build tools (e.g gulp, grunt, webpack, etc.)? They can actually combine all your js into one bundle and include it in index.html automagically.